# Why is there not a funtion `quit = fail ""` for MaybeT?

Tags: haskell

Looking at the source code of `fail` in the `MaybeT` instance of `Monad`:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    fail _ = MaybeT (return Nothing)
```

It's clear that the argument of `fail` is not used. Then why isn't there a cleaner function like `quit :: MaybeT m ()` that saves us from typing `fail ""` everytime? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that a lot of people want to remove `fail` from the `Monad` class altogether, and it seems reasonably likely that this will actually happen soon.

Comment: `fail` exists to handle pattern match failures in do notation. It isn't really intended for human consumption and (as @dfeuer says) arguably shouldn't be a part of the `Monad` typeclass at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is what [`mzero` is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#line-122) for `MaybeT`'s [`MonadPlus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) instance (except that the type is more general than the one you gave: for the `MaybeT` instance, we have `mzero :: Monad m => MaybeT m a`).